# JQuery/HTML5 Slider - allow own input

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile

I'm writing a time registration mobile app in MVC4, and I'm using the slider input-type.

```html
<input type="range" name="time_verdi" id="slider" value="7.5" min="0.0" max="24" step="0.5" data-highlight="true"/>
```

This produces a slider, and a textbox to the left of the slider. However, I want the user to be able to input their own values, for instance 7.25 hours. This can be done now, but when the focus leaves the textbox, it is validated from 7.25 hours to 7 hours. Is there any way of not validating the textbox? I have serverside validation. Thanks.

Comment: can you share the validation code, cause if there is no validation off-course it works as required.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. I'm using JQuery/JQuery Mobile, so the client validation is a part of that library. I want to somehow override the jquery mobile validation, or perhaps just allow input as if the step was sat to "0.1"

Comment: as per W3org, it should work.http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.range.html

Comment: In that case, if you know whether the range input tag is validated by focus event then write your own event handler. like `onfocus='disable();'function disable(){ return false } ` do same for other functions if its calling.

Comment: Ah got it I guess the step is 0.5, so if its below.5 then it scales it down to 7 and if 7.75 then does scale up to 8

Comment: Yeah, I want the slider to have step of .5. If it is .1, it is hard to set the correct value (remember, this is a mobile app). However, you should be allowed to type in as if the step was .1. Will try out the javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can drive the range slider using only input values not matching the step increment, cause the framework code depends entirely on the step (0.5) that you have provided, it will always round off to the nearest value of the step, and if you get rid of this code, it does only drive through the textbox value and not through the slider movement. Please re visit your requirement.

Original code:

```
//from jQuery UI slider, the following source will round to the nearest step
var valModStep = ( newval - min ) % step;
var alignValue = newval - valModStep;

if ( Math.abs( valModStep ) * 2 >= step ) {
    alignValue += ( valModStep > 0 ) ? step : ( -step );
}
var percentPerStep = 100/((max-min)/step);
// Since JavaScript has problems with large floats, round
// the final value to 5 digits after the decimal point (see jQueryUI: #4124)
newval = parseFloat( alignValue.toFixed(5) );
```

Answer (score 0):

I used javascript to change the step when entering the textbox:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on("pageinit", "#registrerPage", function (event) {

            $('#slider').focus(function () {
                document.getElementById("slider").step = ".1";
            });
        });
    </script>
```